# Is there a way to find the closest number in an Array to another inputed number?

Tags: c#

So I have a Visualstudio Forms where I have a NumericUpDown function that will allow users to input a 5 digit number such as 09456. And I need to be able to compare that number to an already existing array of similar 5 digit numbers, so essentially I need to get the inputted number and find the closest number to that.

```
 var numbers = new List<float> {89456f, 23467f, 86453f, };
```

// the list is way longer but you get the idea

```
        var target = numericUpDown.3 ;

        var closest = numbers.Select(n => new { n, (n - target) })
          .OrderBy(p => p.distance)
          .First().n;
```

But the first problem I encounter is that I cannot use a "-" operation on a float. Is there any way I can avoid that error and be able to still find the closest input?

Comment: `I cannot use a "-" operation on a float` you can. You can use subtraction in all numeric types. The *real* problem is that there's no `distance` property in your code. `numericUpDown.3` is invalid and should produce a compilation error.

Comment: What is your *actual* code, *actual* compilation or execution errors?

Comment: What is `numericUpDown.3`?

Comment: What type is `target`? Replace that line with `var target = 23000;` and see what happens.

Comment: `numers.Select(n=>(n,distance=Math.Abs(n-target)).OrderBy(p=>distances).First()` is the lazy and slow way to calculate this, due to the `OrderBy` clause. A far faster way is to loop over the list and check if the current number is closer than the previous closest number. You only need to scan the list once and only need two extra variables to hold the number and difference

Comment: In .NET 5 and earlier you can use MoreLINQ and `MinBy(n=>Math.Abs(n-target))` to get the closest number in a single pass. In .NET 6 MinBy was added to .NET itself

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous type members need names, and you need to use the absolute value of the difference. eg

```
var numbers = new List<float> { 89456f, 23467f, 86453f, };
var target = 3;

var closest = numbers.Select(n => new { n, distance = Math.Abs(n - target) })
  .OrderBy(p => p.distance)
  .First().n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, apart from some issues in your sample(like no `distance` property on `float`) it should work:

```
int target = 55555;
float closest = numbers.OrderBy(f => Math.Abs(f - target)).First();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqS50L

Answer (score 1):

The answers that use `OrderBy` are correct, but have less than optimal performance. `OrderBy` is an O(N log N) operation, but why sort the whole collection when you only need the top element? By contrast, `MinBy` will give you the result in O(N) time:

```
var closest = numbers.MinBy(n => Math.Abs(n - target));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the compilation errors, using LINQ for this is very slow and time consuming. The entire list has to be scanned once to find the distance, then it needs to be sorted, which scans it all over again and caches the results before returning them in order.

**Before .NET 6**

A faster way would be to iterate only once, calculating the distance of the current item from the target, and keep track of which number is closest. That's how eg `Min` and `Max` work.

```
public static float? Closest(this IEnumerable<float> list, float target)
{
    float? closest=null;
    float bestDist=float.MaxValue;
    foreach(var n in list)
    {
        var dist=Math.Abs(n-target);
        if (dist<bestDist)
        {
            bestDist=dist;
            closest=n;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

This will return the closest number in a single pass.

```
var numbers = new List<float> { 89456f, 23467f, 86453f, };
var closest=numbers.Closest(20000);
Console.WriteLine($"Closest is {closest}");
------------------
Closest is 23467
```

**Using MoreLINQ and MinBy**

The same can be done in a single line using the [MinBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) extension method from the MoreLINQ library:

```
var closest=numbers.MinBy(n=>Math.Abs(n-target));
```

**Using MinBy**

In .NET 6 and later, [Enumerable.MinBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.minby?view=net-6.0) was added to the BCL:

```
var closest=numbers.MinBy(n=>Math.Abs(n-target));
```

[The code is similar to the explicit loop](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Min.cs#L504) once you look past the generic key selectors and comparers :

```
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    TSource nextValue = e.Current;
    TKey nextKey = keySelector(nextValue);
    if (nextKey != null && comparer.Compare(nextKey, key) < 0)
    {
        key = nextKey;
        value = nextValue;
    }
}
```